# Change parameter in INI file in Perl

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu, parameters, cgi

I have a question here. Can the parameter in the INI file be change? I know that the value can be change though. But i wonder if the parameter can be change also instead of the value. I show you, for an example, here is the INI file

```
[section 1]
parameter1 = value1
parameter2 = value2
```

Instead of changing the value, is there any perl module or anything can change the **parameter1** and **parameter2** and leave the **value1** and **value2** unchange. If we want to read the value we just use this right :

```
my $file = "file directory";
my $Config = Config::Tiny->read($file);

my $read = $Config->{"section 1"}->{"parameter1"};
```

But how to only change the **parameter1** and **parameter2**

Can this be done? I mean using perl programming. If yes, can anybody show me an example on how to do this. Its for my assignment though. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very simple using [`Config::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/module/Config%3a%3aTiny) but there is no way to rename a value directly - you have to copy the value to an item with the new name and then delete the old one.

This short Perl program demonstrates. It changes `parameter1` to `newparam1` and `parameter2` to `newparam2`. The new config is written to a different file to facilitate testing, but you will probably want to override the original file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Config::Tiny;

my $cfg = Config::Tiny->read('file.cfg');

#print $cfg->{'section 1'}{parameter1};

my $section1 = $cfg->{'section 1'};

$section1->{newparam1} = $section1->{parameter1};
delete $section1->{parameter1};

$section1->{newparam2} = $section1->{parameter2};
delete $section1->{parameter2};

$cfg->write('newfile.cfg');
```

**output**

```
[section 1]
newparam1=value1
newparam2=value2
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot dude. This save me a lot of headaches. :) @Borodin

Comment: @user3463422 Small note: I would probably `delete` and assign in the same line to more quickly communicate your intent:  `$section1->{newparam1} = delete $section1->{parameter1};`

Comment: @Miller: So would I, but I prefer clarity over brevity for people not so familiar with Perl.